# How can I instantiate an instance of a type using a dictionary of property names/values?

Tags: .net, reflection

I know how to do this "manually", that is, loop through the dictionary and assign property values using the key and reflection. I seem to recall, though, a method hanging off of one of the built-in .Net classes for creating class instances out of dictionaries. Only now I can't seem to find it and Google's not helping.

Am I imagining things or is there a one-liner for this?

ex:

```
var obj = CantRememberWhichClass.WithDictionary(Dictionary<string, object> input);
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you mean [`TypeConverter.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx8d838t.aspx)? This is not universally supported, but ***some*** converters report true for `GetCreateInstanceSupported`

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of [PopulateObjectMembers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.populateobjectmembers.aspx), but the API isn't an exact match. Maybe just use reflection instead?

Comment: If you don't know about it, it probably doesn't exist :)

Comment: @Chris - we all have gaps in our knowledge; but I haven't found anything *quite* that matches...